# Value type cannot be locked Using LOCK C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

Why we cannot use value type in Lock C#. I found some of the reason but it doesnot look more convienecing :

" Remember that when you pass a value type for a parameter of type object, it gets boxed (wrapped) into a reference type. This makes it a brand-new object each time this happens. "

"You cannot lock a value type because it doesn't have a sync root record."

Answer (score 5):

A raw value type *has nowhere to store the required information about the lock*. An `int` (`Int32`) for example, is 4 bytes of data ***and nothing else***. An *object*, on the other hand, has an associated few header bytes, in which a lock primitive can be lazily stored when needed (the first time a specific object is locked). It is true that all value-types can be *treated* as objects (by boxing), but that would be useless, as every call to `lock` would box *separately*, so you'd never be talking to the same object - it wouldn't achieve the anticipated result.

As an aside, personally I think it was a mistake to allow you to lock on arbitrary objects. It would seem more obvious and direct for `Monitor` to have been an *instance* type, so you could only lock on specific types. Then this question would be moot.

Comment: In above statement headre bytes are related to sync root record.What is the header bytes here..

Comment: @sudhir the header bytes are part of the *object header*. An *object* (on the heap) contains a few extra bytes (separate to the payload) to indicate what type the object is, and a few other things. One of those other things is the "sync root" token, which is lazily populated.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the copy-by-value semantic of the Value Types.

`lock` uses `Monitor.Enter(yourValueTypeVariable)` beyond the hoods.

There is no relation between the copied value for the two threads other than that they might be equal (By Value) which is a useless information for synchronization purposes.

Consider the below example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 4 + 1;

    Task.Run(() => Method1(x));
    Task.Run(() => Method2(y));
}

private static void Method1(int lockObject1)
{
    lock (lockObject1)
    {

    }
}

private static void Method2(int lockObject2)
{
    lock (lockObject2)
    {

    }
}
```

The default behaviour for ValueTypes is that `lockObject1` and `lockObject2` are equal. But you wouldn't want that behavior right ?

The `Monitor` class needs a reference for the synchronization object, in order to determine if the attempt is on the same block and using the same object or not.